# Selecting Rows from Table with Lastest Import Date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this t-sql script below that I need to modify to insure that there are no duplicate rows from table1. I would like to do that by grabbing the rows that have the most current date in the [ImportedDate] column. Could I get some guidance? 
Thanks

UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION
I need to select all rows in table1 that match in table2. However there are multiple instances of the record in each table. So I also need to ensure that I am only pulling 1 record for each [MIN] number (the latest version) from table1. So for instance the current result set is 20008 records and I should get somewhere less than that by weeding out the duplicates. I'm thinking it needs an inner select.

```
SELECT  mr.Id
       ,mr.F2FResolved
       ,mr.F2FIgnore
       ,mr.[F2FIgnore Always]
       ,REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM([MIN])), '-', '') AS [MIN]
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerLastName)) AS BorrowerLastName
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerFirstName)) AS BorrowerFirstName
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerSSN)) AS BorrowerSSN
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.PropertyStreet)) AS PropertyStreet
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.PropertyZip)) AS PropertyZip
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.NoteAmount)) AS NoteAmount
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.LienType)) AS LienType
FROM    table1 mr
        INNER JOIN table2 d ON LTRIM(RTRIM(MERSMin)) = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.[MIN])), '-', '')
WHERE   ( ( ( mr.[F2FResolved] IS NULL
              OR mr.[F2FResolved] = 0
            )
            AND ( d.[F2FResolved] IS NULL
                  OR d.[F2FResolved] = 0
                )
          )
          OR ( ( mr.[F2FIgnore Always] IS NULL
                 OR mr.[F2FIgnore Always] = 0
               )
               AND d.[F2FIgnore Always] IS NULL
               OR d.[F2FIgnore Always] = 0
             )
          OR ( ( mr.[F2FIgnore] IS NULL
                 OR mr.[F2FIgnore] = 0
               )
               AND d.[F2FIgnore] IS NULL
               OR d.[F2FIgnore] = 0
             )
        )
        AND ( ( mr.[F2FProcessed] IS NULL
                OR mr.[F2FProcessed] = 0
              )
              AND ( d.[F2FProcessed] IS NULL
                    OR d.[F2FProcessed] = 0
                  )
            )
```

In the image you will see that Id = 65759 and 52413 are for the same individual. I would need to only retrieve the 65759 record as it would have the most recent imported date.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with the Answer for anyone looking.

FYI: I know there is extraneous code in the inner select but this statement is dynamically generated from a c# application where the user is able to select the columns they want to view. So the column selection code is only be generated once and added to a string.Format statement twice to output the formatted sql statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mr.Id
       ,mr.F2FResolved
       ,mr.F2FIgnore
       ,mr.[F2FIgnore Always]
       ,REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM([MIN])), '-', '') AS [MIN]
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerLastName)) AS BorrowerLastName
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerFirstName)) AS BorrowerFirstName
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerSSN)) AS BorrowerSSN
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.PropertyStreet)) AS PropertyStreet
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.PropertyZip)) AS PropertyZip
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.NoteAmount)) AS NoteAmount
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.LienType)) AS LienType
FROM    ( SELECT    mr.Id
                   ,mr.F2FResolved
                   ,mr.F2FIgnore
                   ,mr.[F2FIgnore Always]
                   ,REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.[MIN])), '-', '') AS [MIN]
                   ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerLastName)) AS BorrowerLastName
                   ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerFirstName)) AS BorrowerFirstName
                   ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerSSN)) AS BorrowerSSN
                   ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.PropertyStreet)) AS PropertyStreet
                   ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.PropertyZip)) AS PropertyZip
                   ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.NoteAmount)) AS NoteAmount
                   ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.LienType)) AS LienType
                   ,mr.F2FProcessed
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY mr.[MIN] ORDER BY mr.[ImportedDate] DESC ) AS rn
          FROM      Table1 mr
        ) AS mr
        INNER JOIN Table2 d ON LTRIM(RTRIM(MERSMin)) = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.[MIN])), '-', '')
WHERE   ( ( COALESCE(mr.[F2FResolved], 0) = 0
            AND COALESCE(d.[F2FResolved], 0) = 0
          )
          OR ( COALESCE(mr.[F2FIgnore Always], 0) = 0
               AND COALESCE(d.[F2FIgnore Always], 0) = 0
             )
          OR ( COALESCE(mr.[F2FIgnore], 0) = 0
               AND COALESCE(d.[F2FIgnore], 0) = 0
             )
        )
        AND COALESCE(mr.F2FProcessed, 0) = 0
        AND COALESCE(d.F2FProcessed, 0) = 0
        AND rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ORDER BY [ImportedDate] DESC
```

to the bottom of the query.

Comment: This will also return the unwanted duplicate records it will just push them to the bottom of the result set. Not what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery to get the latest date.  I prefer a CTE, as it makes the code clearer.

You could also make things a bit simpler by using `coalesce()` in all your checks whether something is zero or null.

```
with latestdate (latest) as (
   select max([ImportedDate]) from table1
)
SELECT  mr.Id
       ,mr.F2FResolved
       ,mr.F2FIgnore
       ,mr.[F2FIgnore Always]
       ,REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM([MIN])), '-', '') AS [MIN]
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerLastName)) AS BorrowerLastName
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerFirstName)) AS BorrowerFirstName
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.BorrowerSSN)) AS BorrowerSSN
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.PropertyStreet)) AS PropertyStreet
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.PropertyZip)) AS PropertyZip
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.NoteAmount)) AS NoteAmount
       ,LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.LienType)) AS LienType
FROM    table1 mr
INNER JOIN latestdate ON [ImportedDate] = latest
INNER JOIN table2 d ON LTRIM(RTRIM(MERSMin)) = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(mr.[MIN])), '-', '')
WHERE   (
          (      coalesce(mr.[F2FResolved],0) = 0
             AND coalesce(d.[F2FResolved] ,0) = 0
          )
          OR (     coalesce(mr.[F2FIgnore Always],0) = 0
               AND coalesce(d.[F2FIgnore Always] ,0) = 0
             )
          OR (     coalesce(mr.[F2FIgnore],0) = 0
               AND coalesce(d.[F2FIgnore] ,0) = 0
             )
        )
        AND coalesce(mr.[F2FProcessed],0) = 0
        AND coalesce(d.[F2FProcessed] ,0) = 0
```

Comment: This returned 0 records. Great suggestion for the COALESCE. Anything to simplify that section is welcome.

Comment: @Tim, this implies the top row from table1 doesn't match anything in table2.  The question said that was the row you wanted, however.

Comment: If you really want the top row from the joined tables, just move `top` to the main query instead of the subquery

Comment: I need to select all rows in table1 that match in table2. However there are multiple instances of the record in each table. So I also need to ensure that I am only pulling 1 record (the latest version) from table1. So for instance the current result set is 20008 records and I should get somewhere less than that by weeding out the duplicates.

Comment: I'm thinking it needs an inner select that will retrieve a dataset of the most recent ImportedDates.

Comment: The results set is 0 records with this example. Also isn't this only going to return the records that have the MAX(ImportedDate) from the with statement? Not all of the records are going to have the dame import date

Comment: @Tim, your requirements keep changing!  Can't answer a question if you don't know what you're asking or don't state it clearly.  Perhaps could you add some sample data to the question and show what rows you want returned?

Comment: The requirements aren't changing. I need all rows from table1 but I need to have the rows with the latest importeddate. Maybe the question wasn't clear enough. I've been updating it for clarification

Comment: @Tim, first you said you wanted "the single row with the latest importeddate from table1".  Then you said you wanted "all rows with the latest importeddate from table1" (this is what the query above gives).  Now you say...?  Maybe the latest row from table1 for each row in table2?  It's not clear.

Comment: The question was updated with a representation of the data. The initial indication for a row was a typo and was corrected.